# Lookup for a element in a list and get the previous elements (both need to be fast)

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm looking for a data structure or a solution which allows me to find an element faster than O(n) **AND** to get the previous elements of the found element

In my case, I have a list of finacial quote **already filled and sorted**, I need to find an element by DateTime, and I need to returns the previous x elements.

I tried with a LinkedList but the find is too slow o(n).
I also thought about using a Dictionary so I can find by DateTime, but I don't know how to loop in reverse order to get the previous elements.

```
class FinancialQuote
{
    public DateTime TradingDate;
    public double Price;

    protected bool Equals(FinancialQuote other)
    {
        return TradingDate.Equals(other.TradingDate);
    }
}

public void Main()
{

    var quotes = new LinkedList<FinancialQuote>();
    // quotes are populated here

    var result = new List<FinancialQuote>();
    var howManyQuotes = 2;

    // the goal here is to find quote4 and returns quote3 and quote2
    var currentNode = quotes.Find(quote4); // O(N) which is too slow 

    for (int i = 0; i < howManyQuotes; i++)
    {
        var previousClose = currentNode.Previous.Value;
        result.Add(previousClose);

        currentNode = currentNode.Previous;
    }
}
```

So my variable Result should contains quote3 and quote2

Comment: *already filled and sorted* Sorted by what? By `TradingDate` that you need to search later?

Comment: Using a dictionary like that is fine if you're never going change the index of anything, that will be faster to index into than using BinarySearch but take more time to set up and obviously it takes more space. Looping backwards is trivial so I don't know what you're asking about. E: and basically, stop using LinkedList. I've literally never seen it being useful. The overhead it comes with outweighs the benefit of constant time insertion and removal in nearly every case.

Comment: @harold: 1) looping forward/backwards through a dictionary is not trivial, it's impossible. 2) I don't understand the statement about `LinkedList` overhead in "nearly every case". Pros and cons are well known, if you need a structure for insertion and removal of many times, and you are working with huge lists, it is *the* structure of choice.

Comment: @Lousy it wouldn't be iteration through a dictionary, the dictionary is just there to get the index, unless I misunderstood his idea. Dictionary doesn't have an order so that would a non-starter anyway. 2) it's a really uncommon case that that actually pays off. Usually, even if you need insertion/removal in the middle, a List still wins. You can make List lose, but it takes effort, because the only thing that's fast about LinkedList is the insertion and removal - anything else, such as finding the insertion point or enumerating it, is slow.

Answer (score 2):

`List` type already guarantees O(1) time to access an element by index. Therefore, you can achieve O(logN) time to find an element of a sorted list by applying binary search algorithm.

After that, you can simply iterate through predecessors of that element.

```
int index = quotes.BinarySearch(searchValue);

if (index >= 0)
{
    int lowIndex = Math.Max(index - howManyQuotes, 0);
    for (int cur = lowIndex; cur <= index; cur++)
    {
        // do something with quotes[cur];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but OP should also clarify what should happen if there is no exact match (because `BinarySearch` will then return bitwise complement of the first larger index, so perhaps the method can still fetch some results).

Comment: That is true. I'm only defending from potential exceptions, nothing more.

Comment: If the list is sorted properly (which is not clear from the question), this is indeed the solution, although `BinarySearch` cannot be use directly to search for property value. So it should be a custom binary search method, but the principle will be the same.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's sorted by datetime

Comment: @Gui Then this should work for you. Just write your own binary search  method which should be trivial.

Comment: `BinarySearch` method has an overload with `IComparer`. It's easy to implement a comparer which only compares timestamps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use a normal `List<FinancialQuote>` which must be sorted on date.

Use the BinarySearch for the index where the DateTime should be (inserted). Use this function also for building the list. It returns a positive index when the dateTime is found (exact match) and a negative index where this datetime should be inserted.

Use that index as upper bound. (iterate 0 to found index)